# Imported Module is undefined Angular4

Tags: angular

Very new to Angular so this is probably a setup issue. But I have a module that is undefined when I try and import it into another module and I think it has to do with the order because when I switch it the other module can't be imported.

My tree looks like this

```
|-- src/
|   |-- app/
|   |   |-- components/
|   |   |   |-- login/
|   |   |   |   |-- login.compact.component.html
|   |   |   |   |-- login.component.html
|   |   |   |   |-- login.component.ts
|   |   |   |   |-- login.service.ts
|   |   |   |   |-- login.module.ts
|   |   |   |-- ...
|   |   |   |-- components.module.ts
|   |   |-- shared/
|   |   |   |-- header/
|   |   |   |-- footer/
|   |   |   |-- navigation/
|   |   |   |-- shared.module.ts
|   |   |-- app.component.html
|   |   |-- app.component.ts
|   |   |-- app.module.ts
|   |   |-- app.routes.ts
```

I was trying to add a compact version of login to my navigation bar

navigation.component.html

```
<nav>
   ....
   <mylogin></mylogin>
</nav>
```

But when I add the `LoginModule` to the `imports` of the `SharedModule` I get this errror `Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'LoginModule'`

In my `app.module.ts` I have

```
import {SharedModule} from './shared/shared.module';

import {ComponentsModule} from './components/components.module';
....
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
],
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SharedModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forRoot(
        APP_ROUTES,
        {enableTracing: true})
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Is this a bad way to structure the app? Or is it wrong to try and import login into the shared module to use in navigation?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't know how you have imported the `LoginModule` into `SharedModule` as you haven't provided the `SharedModule`.

Secondly, if you wish to import one module into another module. You need to add `exports: []` with all the `declarations` that you want to import to the other module. Here's an example:

> Module A

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    CapitalizePipe,
    SentenceCasePipe,
    FirstNamePipe,
  ],
  exports: [
    CapitalizePipe,
    SentenceCasePipe,
    FirstNamePipe,
  ]
})
export class PipesModule {
}
```

> Module B that imports Module A

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    PipesModule,
    NgbModule,
    RouterModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: []
})
export class HomeModule {
}
```

As you can see, the `PipesModule` from module A is imported into module B by adding all the `declarations` in the `exports: []`; which allows them to be able to load on to different modules on demand.

> FYI

Adding things to the `AppModule` will result in all of those things to be loaded into the browser DOM on application load. That means if you add `module`s that are only used in one component; this can result in your application's load time to extend as it needs to all the modules.

So my advice to you is to plan your app as much nested style as possible with **incremental module** loading, making your app loads faster and smoother. An example would be:

```
AppModule
AppComponent
   | PublicModule
   | PublicComponent
         | LoginModule
         | LoginComponnet
                | HomeModule
                | HomeComponent
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to follow the guidelines explained out here (https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#overall-structural-guidelines). And to me navigation should be a core (or as I named, shared) module, but login should not. So how can I use login, in the navigation ?

Comment: In that case, you're going to have to include login in the navigation, so the above example's `Module B` becomes your `SharedModule` and `Module A` becomes the `LoginModule`. If that helps?